# Square roots in $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p^2}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For prime $p$, I understand that each $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p}$ has exactly 2 square roots (as there are at least 2, and the quadratic residues are exactly half of the group (the group is cyclic so we take even exponents of a generator g) so there can't be more than 2 by counting (otherwise there is an element that is a root of 2 different elements). I also understand what happens at $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{pq}$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes as we can use chinese remainder theorem and compute roots separately and get 4 roots).

I however don't understand what happens at $x \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p^2}$ as I am unsure if its cyclic so I think my previous argument doesn't work.

thanks.

Comment: Do you really mean $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ (the cyclic group of order $p^2$) or, maybe, $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ (the finite field with $p^2$ elements)?

Comment: Taking your question as it stands, $\mathbb Z_{p^2}^\ast$ is cyclic, since there are primitive roots modulo $p^2$ (and in fact, modulo $p^n$ with any $n\ge 1$). If $g\in\mathbb Z_{p^2}^\ast$ is some fixed primitive root, then every element of $\mathbb Z_{p^2}^\ast$ is uniquely written as $g^k$ with some $0\le k<p(p-1)$, and the element is a square if and only if $k$ is even.

Comment: (My first intention was to ask what happens for $p=2$ and $p=3$, getting thus also an explicit chance to figure out the notations...)

Comment: Your first statement is wrong: every $x\in\Bbb Z_p^*$ has zero or two square roots. Unless $p=2$, in which case every such $x$ (namely, $x=1$) has one square root.